# DOJO dialog not opening second time after clicking close(x) button on the upper right corner

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, dojo

I have a dialog button named EDIT in my page.

First time when you click on EDIT button,the EDIT pop up window appears. When I close the pop up window by clicking on the Close (x) button located on the upper right corner of the pop up window and click EDIT button again the second time, the pop up window is not appearing(opening). But after clicking on the 'CANCEL' and 'APPLY' buttons located below on the same 'EDIT' pop up window and clicking on EDIT for the second time, the pop up window opens. So there is a problem after clicking on the close button which is not allowing me to open the EDIT window again.

UPDATE:

I found the code(as below) which is not allowing me to open the 'EDIT' dialog the second time and I commented it . But commenting the code caused another problem i.e. when I click on 'CANCEL' or 'APPLY' buttons it is throwing the following error and is not allowing me to open the 'EDIT' button again by throwing the same error.

Comment: Try to create working example on jsFiddle or post only relevant parts of code to get some asnwer...

Comment: Sorry. I removed the extra .js file which might be irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You are destroying the widget on close (`destroyOnClose : true`), so it isn't available to open on the second attempt.

```
/*
 * Overload the _destroyOrHide method in rmt.NewModalPopup so 
 * that the popup will be destroyed instead of closed. (Close
 * doesn't remove the DOM node.)
 */
```

Comment: I tried changing (destroyOnClose : false) also. Even then the pop up did not open second time.

Comment: Did you step through the code (_destroyOrHide) and verify that it in fact is not destroying the idget?

Comment: _destroyOrHide method is not even being called when I click on the close button. Instead the method called close() is being called. I had mentioned the method definition as an update in the main screen.

Answer (score 0):

Befre creating the dialog box please add the below code :

```
if (dojo.byId('displayQualificationPane') != null) {
                        dojo.forEach(dijit.findWidgets(dojo.byId('displayQualificationPane')), function (w) {
                            w.destroyRecursive();
                        });
                    }
                    dojo.destroy(dojo.byId('displayQualificationPane'));
                    if (dijit.byId('displayQualificationPane')) {
                        dijit.byId('displayQualificationPane').destroy();
                    }
```

It will destroy the widget everytime before creating it.

Comment: I tried it. Unsuccessful. The Edit button is not opening second time.

Comment: hey..you need to add the code for destroying the widget (which u have now commented) I guess. Whats the error you are getting when u open the dialog box again after closing it from the (x) button ?

Comment: I am getting the error "Tried to register widget with id==editQualificationsApply but that id is already registered"  when I try to open the 'EDIT' dialog box again.

Comment: can u get the id of that (x) button from firebug ..and destroy it also before creating the dialog box using the code i have shared .

Answer (score 0):

Another technique, similar to Himani's recommendation, but perhaps easier to use, is to ensure that the dialog contents are destroyed after the hide function is called. This way, you don't have to do any complicated checks for this when initializing your components.

```
hide: function() {
    this.inherited(arguments);
    window.setTimeout( dojo.hitch( this, 'destroyRecursive' ), 500 );
}
```

Or perhaps even

```
aspect.after( dialog, 'hide', dojo.hitch( this, function() {
                      setTimeout( function() {
                          dialog.destroyRecursive();
                      }, 500 );
              }));
```